# Ionic 4: BatteryStatus doesn't change

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to get the battery status of the device in my app.

after having installed

```
cordova-plugin-battery-status
@ionic-native/battery-status
@ionic-native/core
```

I put `BatteryStatus` into the module providers.

In the component, I have :

```
batterySubscription: Subscription;
batteryLevel: number = 100;
isBatteryPlugged: boolean = false;

constructor(private batteryStatus: BatteryStatus) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.initSubscriptions();
}

initSubscriptions() {
  this.batterySubscription = this.batteryStatus.onChange().subscribe( (status: 
  BatteryStatusResponse) => {
    console.log(status.level, status.isPlugged);
    this.batteryLevel = status.level;
    this.isBatteryPlugged = status.isPlugged;
  });
}
```

Everything compiled perfectly, but the battery informations never change (as well in the browser as in the app). It doesn't detect neither when I plug the computer nor when the battery level changes.

Has somebody an idea of the problem ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks good to me, but that plugin is so old that it might not be working as expected on newer OSs. You can try and open an issue: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-battery-status/issues

If I were you however, I'd try using capacitor: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/device#getbatteryinfo

Comment: Capacitor works well, but I can't detect battery infos changing ...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the OS you are testing this with, instead of

```
this.battery.onChange()
```

you may get better results from

```
fromEvent<BatteryStatusResponse>(window, 'batterystatus')
```

This is what I have been using with Android 10, and have had the desired behavior from it.

For more reference: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-battery-status/issues/66#issuecomment-527070672

Comment: Unfortunaltely this method doesn't work, and it seems to be the same for some people in the issue you mentioned. Thanks for help !

Comment: Gotcha, one thing I noticed for what its worth, this method may take a long time to pass anything to the subscription, especially in when trying to debug via USB.

Comment: What do you consider as  "a long time" ?

Comment: Minutes potentially. If its plugged into USB and no heavy lift processes are running it may be awhile before the battery changes. I did have more success getting the value when initializing the subscription from the constructor of my service. Ideally they would change this api to return a BehaviorSubject, or at least act like one.

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen to use capacitor with a setInterval to update batteryInfos. If somebody has a better way to do it I am open to read :)